# The marker aint getting removed in the anchor tag after setting things up also

Tags: html, css

guys i need help my marker tag aint getting removed :(

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.navlist{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
text-decoration: none;
}
.navlist li{
text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li a{
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebPage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="body">
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="navlist">
                <li><a href="#aa">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aa">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aa">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aa">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aa">home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I did set it to text decoration to none but it ain't working pls help
I was trying to make a navbar but... it ain't working
And I need it to be removed but it ain't
**Someone Please Tell me how do i remove those markers**
dude let me post the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `list-style: none;` to your ul tag

Comment: is quite normal to miss that properties, they are not very common